# Audio Amplifier Design (CE Amplifier - Class AB Power Amplifier)

Tags: amplifier, audio, bjt, simulation, pspice

I am trying to design a Audio Amplifier which provides a gain of 20db (10V/V). I have managed to design the following circuit but the output voltage gets clipped and clamped. Please find the schematic file at sendspace.com/file/i5rw9n [image: Schematic][image: Obtained Output].

Comment: The input voltage is a sample 250mV peak to peak signal. The expected output at the 8 Ohm (Load) is 2.5 V

Comment: The URL you gave is no good. The schematic has some basic design problems, such as a lack of bypass caps on the power supply leads. Also, normally the first stage drives the output stage directly, not using C3. This could work with some fix's, but it is not a good design.

Comment: @Sparky256 http://www.sendspace.com/file/i5rw9n

Comment: Both my firewall and anti-virus are blocking the download. I cannot open an .sch file anyways.

Comment: It's a PSPICE Student Edition Schematic File. @Sparky256 .

Comment: My OrCad program is at work. It's $8,000 so I did not get a home version. I can only work with .tiff/.pdf/.png/.bmp/.gif/.doc/.vi at home.

Comment: Q3 looks upside down to me

Comment: Gain of the first stage will be massively greater than 10V/V.

Answer (score 1):

Q3's Emitter and Collector are the wrong way around. The Emitter should go to R9 and the Collector to V3.

The power output stage (Q2/Q3) has a voltage gain of slightly less than 1. To get full output voltage swing it must be driven close to both positive and negative supply rails. The input stage (Q1) is powered from +12V only, so it won't be able to produce the +-12V signal required to get full output.

The 8 Ohm load draws a peak current of over 1A at full output voltage, too much for the 2N3904/6. Also resistors R6 and R7 won't supply enough current to drive them at that current. Try a higher load resistance (eg. 50 Ohms) to get more output voltage without distortion.